# ftp_rawlist doesn't list .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, file, ftp, filesystems

I'm using [DirectAdmin](https://www.directadmin.com) and trying to automate the user creation/modification.

I can create users using this PHP [library](https://github.com/omines/directadmin) just fine. But when a user is created, some default files/folders are added:

```
cgi-bin/
    .htaccess
400.shtml
401.shtml
403.shtml
404.shtml
500.shtml
index.html
logo.shtml
```

I also want to delete these files. I've created a function to list all the files/folders recursively and it works fine. It's using/parsing the strings returned from the [`ftp_rawlist()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rawlist.php). The problem is `ftp_rawlist` doesn't list the `.htaccess` file. Since `.htaccess` isn't listed, I can't delete it, and also can't delete the `cgi-bin` folder because it isn't empty.

I could delete the htaccess file explicitly before running the automated delete function, but why bother if there's a way to do it. Besides, if I use this method with a different folder structure (that I don't know if any child folder contains a htaccess file), it'll fail.

Is there a way to force ftp_rawlist to list also the htaccess file?

---

**Update**:

Using the `-a` switch worked. `-A` has no effect, so it should be lowercase, but I guess that's server specific.

For example:

```
print_r( ftp_rawlist($conn, "-a public_html/cgi-bin") );
```

returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => drwxr-xr-x    2 769        test           4096 Mar 13 11:50 .
    [1] => drwxr-xr-x    3 769        test           4096 Mar 13 10:53 ..
    [2] => -rw-r--r--    1 769        test             11 Mar 13 11:44 .htaccess
)
```

It also returns `.` and `..`, so I'm gonna have to filter out these.

**Update 2**:

About the parsing of `ftp_rawlist()` result; I've seen several functions that does the job but none of where readable enough, and I like readable code. So I decided to write my own. Sharing it here in case someone needs it: [ftp_all_files()](https://github.com/akinuri/php-lib/blob/master/ftp_all_files.php).